# Integrating boxtal PHP library into a custom WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, api

I need to integrate [this PHP library](https://github.com/boxtal/php-library) on my WordPress site.
I read that you have to create a plugin or integrate it into the child theme.
So I created a plugin and integrated the PHP library in the plugin folder.

https://ibb.co/vXfJjLj

Here is my plugin

```
    <?php 
/*
Plugin Name: igosen api boxtal
Plugin URI: 
Description: Relier marketplace à boxtal
Author: Serge Astrakhan
Version: 1.0
Author URI: https://igosen.fr/
*/

require_once ('/config/autoload.php');
require_once ('/config/config.php');
```

The require_once request causes a fatal error when activating the plugin.
Can you help me (documentation or example) to be able to correctly load the different elements.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `/` path will try to require the file from your server's root directory. Instead, try something like:

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/config/autoload.php' );
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'config/config.php' );
```

### Reference

- [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/)

Comment: Thank you I succeeded.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please mark it Accepted so that it might help others having a similar problem.